# Getting : no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries

Tags: windows, git, docker, go, amd-processor

I am just getting started with the docker.
I installed the Windows version of the docker and followed some basic steps as given in https://hub.docker.com/?overlay=onboarding.
Unable to build the docker file.

I just cloned a git repo from that
by:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/docker/doodle.git
```

then try to build the docker

```
$ cd doodle\cheers2019 ;
$ docker build -t myrepo/cheers2019 .
```

I am getting the response on the command line:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.31kB
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.11-alpine AS builder
1.11-alpine: Pulling from library/golang
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries
```

DockerFile has

```
FROM golang:1.11-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN go get github.com/pdevine/go-asciisprite
WORKDIR /project
COPY cheers.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o cheers cheers.go

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /project/cheers /cheers
ENTRYPOINT ["/cheers"]
```

My PC specs:
Windows 10 - AMD Ryzen5 Processor

Is there is an issue with the AMD processor? Please suggest me some way to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is followed by [docker/doodle issue 9](https://github.com/docker/doodle/issues/9), and it [includes a workaround](https://github.com/docker/doodle/issues/9#issuecomment-524853363).

But also the simpler advice:

> An alternative is to go to Docker Desktop and select **`Switch to Linux Containers`**.
>
> The problem is due to the `-alpine` part of the tag which unfortunately there is no alpine Linux container which will run on Windows.